# Manage <td> Class tag on click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The issue i am facing is that I have a table with 5 `<td>`. The default color of `<td>` is red, and it changes its color to blue if user click on it first time, and changes to orange if user click on it second time, and third time it changes its color back to red and it goes on.

What I want is that if any of `<td>` has blue or orange color, and user click on any other `<td>` to change it colors, it should alert him "Not allowed, please un-select your previous ", then the user clicks on the selected `<td>` to change its color back to red and then select any other he wants.

here is my code sample:

```js
$(".OpnSeat").on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td") {
    $(this).addClass('openM seat_td');
  } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td openM") {
    $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td');
    $(this).addClass('openF seat_td');
  } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat openF seat_td") {
    $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td openM');
    $(this).removeClass('openF seat_td openM');
    $(this).addClass('OpnSeat seat_td');
  }
});
```

```css
.seat_td {
  width: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.OpnSeat {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.openM {
  color: blue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.openF {
  color: orange;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="OpnSeat seat_td">
      <p class="intxt">1</p>
    </td>
    <td class="OpnSeat seat_td">
      <p class="intxt">2</p>
    </td>
    <td class="OpnSeat seat_td">
      <p class="intxt">3</p>
    </td>
    <td class="OpnSeat seat_td">
      <p class="intxt">4</p>
    </td>
    <td class="OpnSeat seat_td">
      <p class="intxt">5</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

AND HERE IS THE WORKING [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aLy0qrcv/24/)

I am not good in English, I hope i conveyed my issue, any idea or hint in this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `hasClass`.

Here is a small example:

```js
$(".OpnSeat").on('click', function (e) {
  if($(".OpnSeat").hasClass('openM') && !$(this).hasClass('openM')) {
    alert('not allowed');
  } else {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td") {
      $(this).addClass('openM seat_td');
    } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td openM") {
      $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td');
      $(this).addClass('openF seat_td');
    } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat openF seat_td") {
      $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td openM');
      $(this).removeClass('openF seat_td openM');
      $(this).addClass('OpnSeat seat_td');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.seat_td {
  width:60px;
  margin-right:10px
}
.OpnSeat {
  color:red;
  border:2px solid red; 
}
.openM {
  color:blue;
  border:2px solid blue; 
}
.openF{
  color:orange;
  border:2px solid orange; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">1</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">2</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">3</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">4</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">5</p></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Super! This is only an example. I've forgotten to check the orange one, but you can add it too. Now its easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer below code:

https://jsfiddle.net/aLy0qrcv/27/

```
$(".OpnSeat").on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("OpnSeat")) {
  //check for ongoing progress
  //check the presence of blue or orange color on DOM elements other than clicked element
    if ($(".openF").not(this).length > 0 || $(".openM").not(this).length > 0) {
      alert("Not allowed, please un-select your previous ");
      return;
    }
  }

  if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td") {
    $(this).addClass('openM seat_td');
  } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td openM") {
    $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td');
    $(this).addClass('openF seat_td');
  } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat openF seat_td") {
    $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td openM');
    $(this).removeClass('openF seat_td openM');
    $(this).addClass('OpnSeat seat_td');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition to check if different row than this has orange or blue color [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasCLass/) and [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
if($(".OpnSeat").not($(this)).hasClass("openF") || $(".OpnSeat").not($(this)).hasClass("openM") ) { 
      alert("not alowed !");
      return;
    }
```

below a working example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".OpnSeat").on('click', function (e) {
    if($(".OpnSeat").not($(this)).hasClass("openF") || $(".OpnSeat").not($(this)).hasClass("openM") ) { 
      alert("not alowed !");
      return;
    }
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td") {
      $(this).addClass('openM seat_td');
    } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat seat_td openM") {
      $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td');
      $(this).addClass('openF seat_td');
    } else if ($(this).attr("class") == "OpnSeat openF seat_td") {
      $(this).removeClass('openM seat_td openM');
      $(this).removeClass('openF seat_td openM');
      $(this).addClass('OpnSeat seat_td');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.seat_td {
  width:60px;
  margin-right:10px
}
.OpnSeat {
  color:red;
  border:2px solid red; 
}
.openM {
  color:blue;
  border:2px solid blue; 
}
.openF{
  color:orange;
  border:2px solid orange; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">1</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">2</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">3</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">4</p></td>
  <td class="OpnSeat seat_td"><p class="intxt">5</p></td>
</tr>

</table>
```